# Shared memory inter processes

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, process

I have two seperate apps and I want to share some heavy data, namely the image cache and image memory cache, between them.

I'm now unsure if I should use `IPC` with `AIDL` or a shared user id and some shared memory or something else (like a `ContentProvider`). Speed is very important here, cache checks will constantly happen and animations depend on this speed.

My goal is to make the two apps work together perfectly and don't use unnecessary memory as both apps would hold the same data in the memory...

And ideas?

**Edit**

- I want to run each app in their own process
- One app is already published without a shared user id, a shared user id is something I only want to use if this has real benefits

Comment: I'll need to share an in-memory-cache as well. Any suggestions to which method is the best to use for such a use case?

Comment: then use `sharedUserId`: **sharedUserId**
"The name of a Linux user ID that will be shared with other applications. By default, Android assigns each application its own unique user ID. However, if this attribute is set to the same value for two or more applications, they will all share the same ID — provided that they are also signed by the same certificate. Application with the same user ID can access each other's data and, if desired, run in the same process."

Comment: I added some edit to my question. Considering that I want both apps to run in seperate processes, will I have benefits from using sharedUserId instead of IPC with AIDL? If I would not have published one app already, I probably would have just gone the way with a sharedUserId anyways, but this means republishing a new app and I'm unsure that there is any benefit it I want to run my apps in seperate processes

Comment: the benefit of `sharedUserId` is that you could run both apps in the same process so no IPC is needed and your data transfers are blazingly fast - this is what you want, dont you?

Comment: Yes. But I also want to have independent apps (it will be a launcher and a sidebar app to explain the use case). So both apps will run at the same time always and therefore I would like to put each of them in their own process

Comment: then use `ParcelFileDescriptor` - this is the fastest IPC - much faster than `Binder` (and `AIDL` which is build on top of `Binder`)

Comment: Ok, thanks. So for sharing a cache on the file system `ParcelFileDescriptor ` would be the best soution. And for the object sharing (the in-memory-cache)? Maybe what I want to do should not be done and will influence the apps performance to much?

Comment: thanks, I'll check that